# IOS navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe disabled other swipe

Tags: ios, ios8

In IOS 8, it has a new feature to hide bar on swipe. So I tried it. However, it disabled my other swipe. The code is like this:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;

// The follow code works if I comment out the above line
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backBarButtonItemPressed:)];
[swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[swipe setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[self.webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipe];
```

Does any one have similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
 navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
 navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

Comment: I added the following code but it does not work. The right swipe still does not work.                           self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate on your gesture recognizer. i.e. implement the protocol

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Then use the appropriate methods e.g.

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

to determine how the two gesture recognizers should work together.
You can get the navigation gesture recognizer with

`self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 0):

Implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

and override below method:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```